# What is the full list of TFS 2010 EventTypes?

Tags: tfs

I wrote a small app which attempts to subscribe to various events, but can't find a really good explanation or list of all the different event types. Does anyone know what they are? For example, so far I have these:

```
var eventService = this.projectCollection.GetService(typeof(IEventService)) as IEventService;
this.subscriptions.Add(eventService.SubscribeEvent("WorkItemChangedEvent", "", delPref));
this.subscriptions.Add(eventService.SubscribeEvent("BuildCompletionEvent", "", delPref));
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if there is an official overview of the event, but checking "tbl_EventType" in the collection database listed the following events:

1. BranchMovedEvent
2. DataChangedEvent
3. NodeCreatedEvent
4. NodePropertiesChangedEvent
5. NodeRenamedEvent
6. NodesDeletedEvent
7. ProjectCreatedEvent
8. ProjectDeletedEvent
9. CheckinEvent
10. ShelvesetEvent
11. BuildCompletedEvent
12. BuildCompletionEvent
13. BuildCompletionEvent2
14. BuildDefinitionChangedEvent
15. BuildDefinitionUpgradeCompletionEvent
16. BuildResourceChangedEvent
17. BuildStatusChangeEvent
18. WITAdapterSchemaConflictEvent
19. WorkItemChangedEvent
20. TestRunCompletedEvent
21. TestRunStartedEvent
22. CodeReviewChangedEvent

Comment: On top of this there's also notifications (eg StructureChangedNotification), not sure if these are defined in another table.

Comment: Do you know if you can subscribe to it? Sounds interesting for me, because I'm responsible for our TFS, but several people have at least TeamProjectAdmin rights. Unfortunately in TFS2012 I can't find anything in DB named "*StructureChanged*" and MSDN also only shows VS2010 version of the Notification.

Comment: I'm using it currently to create tfs queries whenever a new area is created in tfs 2013 (http://bzbetty.blogspot.co.nz/2012/12/tfs-automation-automatically-creating.html). Although I could probably use a different event instead.

Comment: There is a small difference between Events and Notifications, e.g in your example (TFS plugin) you use the WorkItemChangedNotification, while WorkItemChangedEvent is used for subscriptions for mails or webservice calls. The difference is, that the notification are not saved, because you interfere the saving workflow, while events are already done. So in your Area example you could also have a rule for Area names and if it doesn't fit, you could return an "EventNotificationStatus.ActionDenied" and it will not exist.

Answer (score 1):

can i use all the listed event types to be used in a custom tfs plugin using the ISubscriber interface ? in particular the ProjectCreatedEvent

Answer (score 0):

`BuildCompletionEvent` belong to the [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg216416.aspx). In there you'll find all the classes - search for 'Event'.

You can do similar searches for `WorkItemChangedEvent` and other classes of events.